# how to map a memoryview to a known struct?

Tags: python-3.x, shared-memory, memoryview

There is a game that uses sharedmemory to access the its data.
i can get it by using

```
from multiprocessing import shared_memory
shm1 = shared_memory(name=FalconSharedMemoryArea)
shm1.buf[0:16].tolist()
```

will return some data in a list but i think it is returning in ints.

`len(shm1.buf)` is returning 4096, so its a pretty big list

The structure of the data is defined in c# by the developers

```
    public float x;            // Ownship North (Ft) 
    public float y;            // Ownship East (Ft)
    public float z;            // Ownship Down (Ft)
    public float xDot;         // Ownship North Rate (ft/sec)
    public float yDot;         // Ownship East Rate (ft/sec)
    public float zDot;         // Ownship Down Rate (ft/sec)
    public float alpha;        // Ownship AOA (Degrees)
    public float beta;         // Ownship Beta (Degrees)
    public float gamma;        // Ownship Gamma (Radians)
    public float pitch;        // Ownship Pitch (Radians)
    public float roll;         // Ownship Roll (Radians)
    public float yaw;          // Ownship Yaw (Radians)
    public float mach;         // Ownship Mach number
    public float kias;         // Ownship Indicated Airspeed (Knots)
    public float vt;           // Ownship True Airspeed (Ft/Sec)
    public float gs;           // Ownship Normal Gs
    public float windOffset;   // Wind delta to FPM (Radians)
    public float nozzlePos;    // Ownship engine nozzle percent open (0-100)
```

and so on....

how do i go about mapping the data in memoryview and map it to structure similar to the above? I'm looking for an example that i at least can map the x,y,z out of the memoryview.